# Call method inside of other model

Tags: php, laravel

I got 2 main tables users and pictures. Each user can have same picture(and vice versa) so it have got "hasMany"(and pivot table in between of them) relationship in Elaquent and it works well. Also, I do have as separate table pictures_details. I wonder, is it possible to get the details of pictures_details when accessing from user to picture model?

```
    public function getImages($id, Images $images)
    {
        return $users->with('images')->find($id);

    }
```

So when I have call like that, can I also get data of pictures_details table? I have following method in my Image model

```
    public function imageDetails(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ImageDetails::class, 'image_details_id', 'id');
    }
```

So I thought something like

```
 return $users->with('images')->find($id)->with('imagedetails');
```

Will work but its not. Can you tell me how to achieve this? Or it is wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to edit ArSeN's answer. May be it would be more correct if

```
$users->with(['images.imagedetails'])->find($id);
```

Comment: If it is written in separate with function, then it means  it attempting to get imagedetails of user model,not image model. For that reason I wrote as get related imagedetails of image model of user =) like "images.imagedetails"

Comment: that could just be `images.imagedetails` ... it has to load `images` to get to `imagedetails` so `images` by itself is redundant  `;)`

Comment: thank you lagbox, I'll now edit my answer =)

Answer (score 1):

`find($id)` returns a single model, not the eloquent query, you cant do joins there.

Switch them around:

```php
$users->with('images')->with('imagedetails')->find($id);
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it. 'imagedetails' responds with null